# How to return string from JavaScript file to Ajax request

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax

I have a JavaScript file which uses an Ajax call to another JavaScript file (which runs server commands and produces a JSON result string).

```
 $.getJSON("fileWithServerData.js", function (data) {

    //use data here
});
```

*No PhP here!*

How can I then return my JSON string to the Ajax call?

```
var socket;

socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5000');

socket.on('Id', AFunction);


function AFunction(data) {

   //send data back to the calling JavaScript file
   //???
   //???
   console.log(data) // does NOT work
   //???

}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Your tags suggest that you have some server side code written using Node.js which outputs JSON. If it isn't working, then you'll have to show us *that* code.

Comment: The JSON string should be in the response body.

Comment: simply `console.log(data)` , assuming that your API endpoint work

Comment: I'm guessing you want to get the output from whatever code runs in `fileWithServerData.js`? `eval` would be your only option here. How you'd direct the "output" to a variable is strictly depended on the code in `fileWithServerData.js`.

Comment: I have just posted the fileWithServerData.js - which has data that I am trying to return to the calling AJAX code/file.